# Is there any way to hide or not show some fields which is in Model , but i don't need that in my Rest docs Payload

Tags: spring-restdocs

Not to display some fields in Rest docs which is in my Model.

I have a field which is mandatory for my logic and i couldn't do JsonIgnore to it, because I'm using it for my response and things. But I don't need that field in Restdocs payload. Please help.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865427/document-hierarchical-json-payload-with-spring-rest-docs/32870190#32870190) help?

Comment: it was kinda close , but not what i'm looking for ... anyway thanks for your effort..

Comment: No problem. Can you expand your question a bit then please to help me to understand exactly what it is that you are looking for?

Comment: Table(name = "dummyTable")
public class dummyTable implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

Column(name = "DESCRIPTION_TEXT")
  private String description;

Column(name = "IS_SHOW_DESC")
  private Boolean isShowDesc = false;

i dont want this last field isShowDesc in my RestDocs Payload. @AndyWilkinson

Comment: Can you edit your question with an update? The formatting in a comment makes it hard to read.